# Sort Posts by 'ACF' custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress website with enfold theme. i want to sort the post within a masonry based on an id that i added to the posts using Custom fields.
for example the post titles are a , b , c. each one of them has an id. and they belong to category "cat" and the cat category is selected in masonry. now i want to sort the items in masonry by my custom id.
[this link](https://kriesi.at/documentation/enfold/blog-post/#toggle-id-26)

defines a function for customizing sort options. how can i add my meta key to this code?
i also tried to use [this](https://kriesi.at/support/topic/portfolio-order-by-custom-field-acf/) but the key is not displaying in sort options.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar recently, possibly this code will help you out. Add it to your functions.php

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','my_sort_custom',10,2);
function my_sort_custom( $orderby, $query ){
    global $wpdb;

    if(!is_admin() && is_category()) 
        $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."postsmeta.MY_META_KEY ASC, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date DESC";

    return  $orderby;
}
```

Comment: thanks but it does not work. with this code all my posts are displaying even if they are not  on the selected category. it also does not sort my category.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you out: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/

Comment: the problem is i can only use the enfold code because my posts are within the masonry and the goal is sorting the elements inside the masonry and none of these codes can solve the problem.